# Execute procedure for all rows

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a code that takes **employee_id** as the parameter from the table1 and gets the name and nationality of the employees. The code is shown below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE emp_info (
  e_id IN table1.employee_id%TYPE
)
IS
  e_name     table1.full_name%TYPE;
  e_nation   table1.nationality%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT full_name, nationality
  INTO e_name, e_nation
  FROM table1
  WHERE employee_id = e_id and rownum = 1; 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Name=' || e_name || '  Country=' || e_nation);

  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS
  THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('No data found for ' || e_id);
END;
```

The procedure works but the problem is at executing the procedure. I want all the values at the same time. How can i do that? I think it has to do something with Loop Cursor's but I could not manage it.

Also, you see the

```
   rownum = 1
```

line. I actually wanted it to skip the parts with multple values. How can i do that? Thanks.

Comment: Which RDBMS u r using?

Comment: What exactly you mean by _all values at the same time_? You could provide expected result set?

Comment: I'm using Oracle Database

Comment: I mean there are many values in full_name and nationality. I can't write: execute emp_info(employee_id) What do i need to do about that?

Comment: @Solijoli Have a look at [this](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/implicit-vs-explicit-cursors-in-oracle-plsql.php#select-into-vs-fetch-2)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to use a cursor to read and process all the rows in the table which match the selection criteria. Something like the following may be of use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE emp_info (
  e_id IN table1.employee_id%TYPE
)
IS
BEGIN
  FOR aRow IN (SELECT full_name, nationality
                 FROM table1
                 WHERE employee_id = e_id)
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Name=' || aRow.FULL_NAME ||
                          '  Country=' || aRow.NATIONALITY);
  END LOOP;  
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('No data found for ' || e_id);
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: ' || SQLCODE || ' ' || SQLERRM);
END;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Can you tell me how do you execute this procedure?

Comment: If you're calling it from SQL*Plus you'd use: `EXEC EMP_INFO(12345);` where 12345 is the EMPLOYEE_ID to be queried for. If you're calling it from PL/SQL you'd use `EMP_INFO(12345);`. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a cursor for this. Also, you can extend it slightly to return either all employees OR just the one. If you want one specific record, then pass the id to the proc. If you want all records, pass NULL..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE emp_info(e_id IN table1.employee_id%TYPE)
AS

  CURSOR c_employees(e_id IN table1.employee_id%TYPE) IS
    SELECT full_name, nationality
    FROM table1
    WHERE employee_id = e_id OR e_id IS NULL;

  r_employees c_employees%rowtype;

BEGIN

  OPEN c_employees(e_id);
    LOOP
    FETCH c_employees into r_employees;
    EXIT WHEN c_employees%NOTFOUND;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Name=' || r_employees.full_name || '  Country=' || r_employees.nationality);      

    END LOOP;
  CLOSE c_employees;

END;
```

Then do:

```
EXEC emp_info(1);
```

to return just 1 record (for employee_id 1). Or

```
EXEC emp_info(NULL);
```

to return all records.